# Stuck trying to import text file contents to a new tag in an XML file in python

Tags: python, xml, excel, parsing, text

I've been spending weeks searching around trying to figure this out, but I keep ending up not quite finding what I need.

I'm new to Python as someone recommended to me it's a good language to quickly manipulate XML files.  But I'm struggling quite a bit with it, especially for this task.

The issue is this.

I have an Excel-created XML file.  It has a tree structure that looks like this:

```
<root>
  ...
  <Row>
    <Entry_No>52</Entry_No>
    <Waterfall_Name>Switzer_Falls</Waterfall_Name>
    <Continent__Super_Region>North America</Continent__Super_Region>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <State__Province>California</State__Province>
    ...
    <scenic_rating>2</scenic_rating>
    <difficulty_rating>3.5</difficulty_rating>
    <distance>4.6 miles round trip (to base of main drop)</distance>
    <time_commitment>3.5 hours (to base of main drop)</time_commitment>
    <GPS_Coordinates>34.25828, -118.15474</GPS_Coordinates>
    ...
    <File_directory>./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/</File_directory>
    <Introduction>introduction-switzer-falls.html</Introduction>
    <Directions>directions-switzer-falls.html</Directions>
    ...
    <Post_Slug>california-switzer-falls.html</Post_Slug>
  </Row>
  ...
</root>
```

I'd like to add new tags that are populated with the contents of the files I'm pointing to like this:

```
<root>
  ...
  <Row>
    <Entry_No>52</Entry_No>
    <Waterfall_Name>Switzer_Falls</Waterfall_Name>
    <Continent__Super_Region>North America</Continent__Super_Region>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <State__Province>California</State__Province>
    ...
    <scenic_rating>2</scenic_rating>
    <difficulty_rating>3.5</difficulty_rating>
    <distance>4.6 miles round trip (to base of main drop)</distance>
    <time_commitment>3.5 hours (to base of main drop)</time_commitment>
    <GPS_Coordinates>34.25828, -118.15474</GPS_Coordinates>
    ...
    <File_directory>./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/</File_directory>
    <Introduction>introduction-switzer-falls.html</Introduction>
    <Directions>directions-switzer-falls.html</Directions>
    ...
    <Post_Slug>california-switzer-falls.html</Post_Slug>
    *<Introduction_Body>a bunch of text taken directly from "introduction-switzer-falls.html" talking about the waterfall complete with links and photo tags</Introduction_Body>
    <Directions_Body>a bunch of text taken directly from "directions-switzer-falls.html" talking about how to drive to the waterfall complete with links and photo tags</Directions_Body>*
  </Row>
  ...
</root>
```

I'm trying to do this because I can't directly put body text into the cells of Excel due to its per-cell character limit (otherwise, I'd have the XML I want in one shot).  So I have to somehow script up a way to do this.

I have the body text offline in files with a specific file structure hinted at in the example above in the tag "File_directory").  I was thinking that I could use that file pointer to open up the file called out by the XML file, then dump into a new tag (these are the "Body" tags shown in the example above) in the related Row tag the desired contents.

Since I was told Python (using elementTree) is the language (and library) to do this in, I'm giving it a shot, but I guess I can't get my head wrapped around the right way to think about this problem.

Can anyone suggest the simplest and most intuitive way (for a Python newbie like me) to do this?

Thanks,
Johnny

Because I'm a Python Newbie, all I have to show for my efforts is the following code...

```
try:
  import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
  import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

data_file = 'WoW Database for WP 2016-09-19.xml'

tree = ET.ElementTree(file=data_file)
root = tree.getroot()
```

It's the part that comes next that I'm confused.  I'm afraid all I have so far is to print everything out (from looking at the stuff literature in the web), but not much else (like how to get at my elements) or even how to apply the solution that was provided below in the context of this imported tree.  So all I have to show for is the following code...

```
for element in root:
  print("PARENT: ", element.tag, element.attrib, element.text)
  for all_tags in element.findall(".//"):
    print("CHILD: ", all_tags.tag, all_tags.attrib)
    if all_tags.text:
      print(all_tags.text, all_tags.tail)
```

Can I get specific python syntax and code on how to write a new XML file in the desired manner described at the top of this post?

Thanks,
Johnny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: More XML-ish code sample

XML is a tree or hierarchy structure starting at a "root" element. Underneath that root element will be top level elements that generally correspond to major objects or ideas. Each element will usually have sub-elements that "describe" the element in some way. If this organization isn't clear, I would highly recommend doing more research on XML at [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/).

Libraries like elementTree help navigate that hierarchy. You can see this in the code you posted. First you have a loop:

```
for element in root: # 'for' in Python really means 'for each'
```

This navigates to each top level element in the document. In the case of the XML you posted above,  is the top level element. All of the tags below each  are sub-elements.

Below incorporates some of your code with examples from [Elements and ElementTrees](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm#searching-for-subelements). This is untested but represents what I would try first given the information at hand.

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

data_file = 'WoW Database for WP 2016-09-19.xml'

tree = ET.ElementTree(file=data_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for element in root: # 'for' in Python really means 'for each'
    directory = element.find('file_directory').text
    introduction = element.find('Introduction').text
    directions = element.find('Directions').text
    # I don't know what tag to use in the html file. Assuming body.
    # this gets text from file and creates Introduction sub-element with text
    intro_tree = ET.ElementTree(directory+introduction)
    intro_text = intro_tree.find('body').text
    intro = SubElement(element,'Introduction')
    intro.text = intro_text
    # Do the same for Directions
    .
    .
    .
# After the loop, write the file back with new elements added
tree.write(data_file)
```

This should give you a good push in the right direction. If not, comment again and I'll refine more.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I have a follow-up question.  Though I'm not sure how to do that in this forum since it seems like a carriage return terminates the comment.  How do I post follow up code in this thread?

Comment: you could add an edit to the original question, but most times follow-up questions are better as new questions referencing the previous question. This makes it easier to search for the new question and keeps each question to 1 topic.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to follow up on the answer.  How do I... "navigate to <post-slug> tag" in Python?, "add new tag in the desired position" (I only know of append which puts the new tag at the end and insert which requires numerical index I think)?, and "add content under tag" in Python?

Comment: So I gave the code a shot, and I'm getting an error message complaining about the directory = element.find('file_directory').text statement saying AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.  Is this because I have some rows that don't yet have the <File_directory> subelement populated?  How would I put a check in there to go forward with the processing if it exists, else move on to the next line?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what is going on. You can check for None: if element.find('file_directory') is not None: directory = element.find('file_directory').text

Comment: so it looks like I have to make checks for each of the tags like Introduction and Directions.  As I got further into the code at the intro_tree, how do I check for both the existence of directory and introduction?  what does the intro_tree.find('body').text do if a tag for "body" doesn't exist yet (I'm introducing say "Introduction_Body" or "Directions_Body")?  Is the following line replacing the file pointer in "Introduction" with the text gained from within the file referred to in the file pointer (in this case "./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/introduction-switzer-falls.html")?

Comment: You check for existence exactly the same way for all of them - do a search. After the search if the variable contains None, then the tag doesn't exist. I don't understand your last question.

Comment: So I'm having trouble with the intro_text, intro, and intro.text statements.  I also don't understand how I can look at what's inside intro_tree as it only prints the memory location <ElementTree object at 0x025A8F50).  The intro_text statement returns an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'text'.  I suspect it's because it presumes there's a 'body' tag in there when it doesn't exist?  I wasn't sure what the intent of that statement was. The intro statement returns error saying NameError: name 'SubElement' is not defined.  What were the intro and intro.text statements trying to do?

Comment: Look, you can't keep asking questions in the comments. My answer fixed your original question so please mark it correct. Most of the answers you need are in the tutorial I linked in the original answer above but in any case you should open a new question.